# How generate width html element to fill rest of width window

Tags: html, css

I would ask how i can set css to set width of element to fill rest of width window screen  without using unit of measure (px, pt, et).

for example i have two div

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

some css

```
#div1{
   width:200px;
   height: 40px;
   float: left;
   border: 1px solid black;
}
#div2{
  width: // here what i should set to get rest of window screen until 100%,
         // depending on resolution. When i try set param auto this param 
         // work that resize my div when i put something into, but i except 
         // at start already set rest of window width. It is possible to set 
         // this value without using javascript only in CSS??
  height: 40px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also use table layout with `display: table` and `display: table-cell`, but for this approach you need a wrapper. [See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eNbV8/)

Comment: here is best solution.

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to do much to make what you want. I made a little js fiddle for you to see.
HTML:

```
<div id="div1">1</div>
<div id="div2">2</div>
```

CSS#:

```
#div1{
    height: 40px;
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    background: blue;
}
#div2{
    height: 40px;
    background: red;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M82pu/1/)

Comment: Try to have a lot of text inside #div2 and look what is going on. #div1 is simply float, so text in #div2 will go under #div1.

Answer (score 0):

I went through the same problem. I proceeded as follows:

```
body {
 width: 100% ;
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
}

#div1{
 position:relative;
 width:200px;
 height: 40px;
 float: left;
 border: 1px solid black;
}

#div2{
 position:relative;
 width:calc(100% - 200px);
 height: 40px;
 float: left;
 border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also just use flexbox to achieve your goal.
HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper background">
  <img src="images/ant.png" class=logo>
  <div class=leftbox>
    <h1>Ant Arni</h1>
  </div>
  <div class=rightbox>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><a href=#>Link 1</a></td>
        <td><a href=#>Link 4</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><a href=#>Link 2</a></td>
        <td><a href=#>Link 5</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><a href=#>Link 3</a></td>
        <td><a href=#>Link 6</a></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
}
.leftbox {
    background: red;
    width: 200px;
}
.rightbox {
    background: yellow;
    flex: 1;
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fung6pt9/)

"flex: 1" means, you're changing the flex-grow property of the item. You can read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow).

Answer (score -1):

use display: inline-block; on #div2

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
#div1{
   width:200px;
   height: 40px;
   float: left;
   border: 1px solid black;
}
#div2{
    clear:left;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tZfQL/)